# What determines if a Wrinkler will spawn an upgrade?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I've noticed that after a while, say a couple of hours, I can usually get 2 upgrades (eg. eggs or seasonal cookies) from the 10 wrinklers. But if there aren't the full 10 wrinklers or if I have only left it for a few minutes I never get upgrades.

What is required to see an upgrade spawn?

I understand they are random but is there anything else required for them to spawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Wiki](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Wrinkler):

If the current season is Halloween, a popped Wrinkler also has a 5% chance of unlocking one of the 7 Halloween cookie types.

Now we know that it also affects the other seasonal events. As you can read [here](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Easter_season#Upgrades). Their is now %-Base mentioned but i'll asume it is the same. Waiting to get 10 Wrinklers does not increase the chance per se, except you have more goes in one turn.

However you do get a CpS increase by keeping them alive for some time. Also you should note that "if the Wrinkler has not yet reached the big cookie, it will not drop any cookies or upgrades when killed".